Is there another way to prove the sum equality below without using Parseval's Theorem? Is LHS defined for $k=1$?
Corollary
Let $k$ be a positive odd integer. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{\pi m : m \equiv 1 \pmod 2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x) = x^k$ with $$f(x) = f(x + 2\pi m)$$ (i.e., $f$ is $2\pi$ - periodic). Using Fourier series, I found that the $C_n$ coefficient is defined as:
$$
\begin{equation}
C_n =
  \begin{cases} 
      0, & n=0 \\
      -\frac{1}{2}iB_n, & n \geq 1 \\
      \frac{1}{2}iB_{|n|}, & n \leq -1 
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
for all integers $n$, where
$$B_n = 2 \cdot k! \cdot \pi^{k-1} \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^{n+m} \ \cdot L(k-2m+1)}{n^{2m+1} \cdot  \pi^{2m}} $$
for which $n$ has to be positive integers.
I showed the following corollary using Parseval's Identity (Michael Penn's Explanation Video):
For all positive odd integers $k$, we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left(\sum_{m=0}^{k} {\frac{(-1)^m L(k-2m+1)}{n^{2m+1}\pi^{2m}}} \right)^2} = 
\frac{\pi^2}{(4k+2)(k!)^2}$$
where $$L(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{1+it}}{(1+it)^z}dt$$ for all complex numbers $z$, and $i^2 = -1$, also known as the Reciprocal Gamma function.
With $k=1$, however, the left-hand-side equation is the Dirichlet series $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ because $L(1-2+1) = L(0)=0$.
Questions

Is the corollary true? I was struggling to find the LHS equation when $k=1$ (i.e., if $L(0) = 0$ or not).
Is there another way to prove such equation without using the Parseval's Identity?

Extras
If anyone needs to see the proof procedure, let me know. It's broad to type the whole proof here, so that's why I didn't include it here.
